# Why does Task.Factory.StartNew() need an overload with CancellationToken?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I created a method with the `CancellationToken` as an argument, and used it in the Task, and everything worked fine. So why is there [an overload for `StartNew` with the token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988458%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? Does it have some effect that prevents possible race conditions that my code didn't have, and therefore *would* be necessary in other cases?

Why `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoNow(), cancellationTokenSource.Token);`

instead of: `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoNow(cancellationTokenSource.Token));` ?

Comment: One reason is so you can create anonymous methods that use cancellation tokens without the token being a parameter to the method. I use the overload extensively for anonymous methods.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks. So there's no _need_ to use this overload. Am I correct? If so - you can transform your comment into an answer.

Comment: The overload exists for the same reason there are other ways to create a `Task` object (including `Task` constructors) with a `CancellationToken`. Please narrow your question so that it is more specific; when you read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx), what is it about a `Task` being assigned a `CancellationToken` that you don't understand?

Comment: @ispiro Just like any other overloaded method, you don't *need* to use it if it doesn't apply to your situation. I don't want to post it as an answer because its not really a complete explanation of your question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho What I don't understand is: Is it there because it _has_ to be there (like we don't want to cancel a `BackgroundWorker ` with a simple variable because that's not thread safe), or is it there only for convenience.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking if you _have to pass one_? If so, I would have thought the presence of overloads without the parameter would be a sufficiently obvious answer to that question. If you are asking whether the overloads _have_ to be there, then yes they do...since the `StartNew()` method implicitly creates a new `Task` object, if you want a `CancellationToken` to be passed to the `Task` constructor, the only way to do that is to have a `StartNew()` overload that itself allows one to be passed to it.

Comment: @RonBeyer Obviously if it doesn't apply - I don't need to use it. See my previous comment explaining why I thought the overload might be important.

Comment: @ispiro I'm as confused as Peter, the overload is important otherwise it wouldn't be there, I would go through some examples of using the `Task.StartNew` with cancellation tokens to see why it can be useful or needed in certain situations.

Comment: @PeterDuniho `the presence of overloads without the parameter would be a sufficiently obvious answer to that question` - No. They would be there for _when I won't be using_  a CancellationToken . As for the end of your comment - as I've said - I've tried passing the CancellationToken to my method and it worked fine, so it does not _have_ to be there.

Comment: @PeterDuniho But never mind, I understand that you two are saying that the overload is only there for convenience. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @RonBeyer See my previous comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at parameter description from the link you've posted:

> The CancellationToken that will be assigned to the new task.

The keyword here is *assigned*.
Here's the sample, when token was passed to `StartNew`:

```
var cts1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
var t1 = Task
.Factory
.StartNew(() =>
{
     cts1.Cancel();
     cts1.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}, cts1.Token)
// this continuation will be fired
.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("t1 was cancelled"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
```

and another one without passing it:

```
var cts2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
var t2 = Task
.Factory
.StartNew(() =>
{
     cts2.Cancel();
     cts2.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
})
// this continuation will **not** be fired
.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("t2 was cancelled"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
```

In the second sample you'll get `OperationCancelledException` within task body, but the continuation won't be fired, since task won't enter `Cancelled` state. Instead of this, state of task will be `Faulted`, which is, obviously, wrong if your code distinguish these two states.

Comment: Won't an `if (token.IsCancellationRequested) throw new Exception();` have the same effect (in the second case in my question)?

Comment: Note that in the first case, you do not even enter the first task because the token was cancelled. You immediately go to the continuation.

Comment: OK. I see you've edited your answer to answer this. So it is important in this case. But from _this_ being the difference, I assume that if I don't need it - it _will_ be safe to use the second type of code in my question. Right?

Comment: @ispiro: define "safe", please. If you mean thread-safety, `CancellationToken` is thread-safe.

Comment: @Dennis I thought that the existence of such an overload might imply that in some cases it _won't_ be safe to use a CancellationToken (unless it's passed through this overload). It seems like everyone is saying that's not so. Thanks.

Comment: @ispiro Its not that it is not "safe". It is that the semantics around cancellation with `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` will be different.